# Nodal voltage analysis logic

Tags: nodal-analysis

[image]

I'm doing nodal voltage analysis on a circuit (zoomed in and cut out all but the relevant part in the picture), and ran into a situation I have no clue how to tackle. I don't understand how to figure out the equation for the current from V2 toward V3 and vice versa. If the resistors weren't there then it would be no problem, but their involvement trips me up.

Embarrassingly, even seeing the answer (V2-(V3-Va))/2R and (V3-(V2+Va))/2R I still don't get it. I would love if someone could help me figure out how to approach this.

(I know this is a noob question and I'm sure this kind of question has been addressed before, but I couldn't find one after looking through the first 10 or so suggestions, so here goes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In branches that just have series-connected passive components, you can rearrange like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEBNnU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This should make the voltage terms more explicit.

Comment: That makes a whole lot of sense and immediately clears it up. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just popping back in to really emphasize my thanks, this was really one of those facts "hiding in plain sight" that is super-useful once you helped me realize it. I'm new to this, and it's so cool that there are people on this forum bothering helping noobs like myself out.

Comment: Glad we were able to clear some stuff up for you!